# Regain control of PR2 after interactive manipulation

Tags: ros, rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone

Is there any way to regain control of PR2 after interactive manipulation, in simulation, using Rviz?

The problem I am stuck with is, I interact with robot's arms using "interact" tab in Rviz interactive manipulation and then try tucking them using pr2_tuckarm.py, but the robot doesn't respond to it. Even after closing Rviz interactive manipulation (both robot.launch and desktop.launch) I am not able to tuck robot's arms. The only solution I currently have with me is relaunching pr2_gazebo, but I am sure there must be a better way of doing it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61242/regain-control-of-pr2-after-interactive-manipulation/) by [Ashesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4149/ashesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I figured out the answer to this myself. What happens is, ROS interactive manipulation stops the controllers. So in order to regain control of PR2 one should restart the controllers using the following command:

rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager start <controller_name>

In my case the controller_name = r_arm_controller

---

Originally posted by [Ashesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4149/ashesh/) with karma: 16 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-04-22**:
It might be sufficient to click on the grippers in rviz so the 6-dof controls disappear, which disables the cartesian controller.

**Comment by [Ashesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4149/ashesh/) on 2013-04-22**:
Actually, I guess this doesn't help. As soon as one starts interacting with the robot via Rviz, the controllers are stopped. One can run rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager, to get the status of controller.